# Limit of $n(a^{1/n}-1)$ as $n \to \infty$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

Show that $\lim(n(a^{1/n}-1)) = \ln(a)$

---

In the context of sequences, I'm not sure how to prove that this is the limit of the sequence. I was trying to convert the expression as follows:

$n(a^{1/n}-1) = \ln(a)\displaystyle\frac{n(e^{\ln(a)/n}-1)}{\ln(a)}$

Then, we can set $\displaystyle\frac{\ln(a)}{n} = 1/x$ to then have:

$\lim(n(a^{1/n}-1)) = \ln(a)\lim({x(e^{x}-1)})=\ln(a)$

Using the result that $\lim(n(e^{n}-1)) = 1$ (both $n$ and $x$ will tend to $\infty$). However, I'm not satisfied with this answer, as I don't think that it is possible to simply set $\displaystyle\frac{\ln(a)}{n} = x$, as then it would be a sequence of in which $x \in \mathbb{R}$, not $x \in \mathbb{N}$ as it should be for a sequence. Is there any other way to solve the problem?

Thank you for your time and patience.

Comment: You mean $(e^x - 1)/x$. Also as n tends to infinity, x tends to 0.

Comment: Sorry, I meant settinng $\ln(a)/n = 1/x$.

Answer (score 5):

$$\displaystyle \lim_{n \to \infty} n(a^{1/n}-1) = \left . \lim_{x \to 0^+} \frac{(a^x-1)}{x} = \frac{d}{dx}(a^x) \right |_{x=0}=\ln(a)$$

Here, I used the substitution $x=\frac{1}{n}$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but is there a way to do it without derivatives? My analysis class hasn't touched that topic yet, we've only done sequences (not functions).

Comment: @fogvajarash the problem is that this is essentially a result about derivatives in disguise. Depending on what kind of limits you have covered (like the one you posted about $n(e^n-1)$) it could be attacked without derivatives, but it would essentially be missing the point, the fundamental nature of the problem. Which is why any such solution would at best be somewhat clumsy, and not that natural.

Answer (score 2):

An idea with l'Hospital:

$$\lim_{x\to\infty}x(a^{1/x}-1)=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{a^{1/x}-1}{\frac1x}\stackrel{\text{l'H}}=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\left(-\frac1{x^2}\right)\log a\;a^{1/x}}{-\frac1{x^2}}=\log a$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**: If you like to use the squeeze theorem, consider this inequality for $x \in (0,1)$:

$1+x+\dfrac{x^2}{2} < e^x < 1 + x + \dfrac{3x^2}{2}$